# Stop debugger in web browser when object value changed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, firebug, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

I have an `<input type="hidden">`. I need to see when it's value changes. I have many JavaScript files changing it's value.

I can just go everywhere where values are changed and add the `debugger` statement, but it will take lot of time. I have learned about [Object.watch()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0500__Object-Oriented/Objectwatch.htm) but it only executes a specific function *after* the value got changed, though I want to see *where* it changed in code, not *when*.

Is there any way to achieve that, maybe by outputting the line number and JavaScript filename or stopping debugger in the web browser?

Comment: `Object.watch` is a custom Firefox API. Internet Explorer has never supported it anyway.

Comment: Hidden elements are usually populated with values in the submit handler for the form. you could search with the debug tab for ".value = " or use the DOM Explorer to see if has a hard value in the value="some hidden value" attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DOM change breakpoints got your back.

1. Go to **Elements** panel of DevTools.
2. Find the element in the HTML pane.
3. Right-click on the element.
4. Select **Break On** > **Attribute Modifications**.

If you need to view changes to the value of the element too, then right-click on the parent of the element, and select **Subtree Modifications**.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will throw a `Cannot assign to read only property..` error (with stack trace) which you can catch (or view in dev tools):

```
'use strict';
var o = {a: 29};
throwOnChange(o, 'a');

// as much code as you like here..

o.a++; // this will throw an error

function throwOnChange(obj, prop) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
    value: obj[prop],
    writable: false
  });
}
```

Just use it on your `input.value` analogously.

Two notes though:

1. You must `'use strict'` for it to work, otherwise it would just ignore the assignment.
2. Please see [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Hope this helps.